# Find Shortest Path

Tags: algorithm, graph

There’s a `M*N` grid, which was filled by black and white color. Given the start point and end point. Only white points could be passed, how to find the shortest path between start and end?

Any thoughts will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Use Dijkstra or Floyd-warshall Algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple algorithm for that matter, but some of the important algorithms are :

[Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

[image: Dijkstra animation]

[Bellman Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

[image: Bellman Ford image]

[Floyd Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

[image]

Even [BFS Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) could be choice.

[image: BFS animation]