# Performant Graph algorithm to find path from node to root in a directed graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, directed-graph

I have a directed graph with a special root node from which all other nodes are reachable.

It is quite easy to find an arbitrary algorithm to find all pathes from a giving node to the root, for example this [solution (DFS) using LinkedHashSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices).

Well, this algorithm works well for small graphs but with larger graphs it doesn't come to an end in a reasonable amount of time.

My example graph has 129 nodes and 200 edges. In my eyes **not** an extremly **HUGE** graph...

Can somebody give me a hint how to solve this problem efficiently?

Maybe we can make use of other properties of my graphs. They all are:

- connected
- directed with loops
- have a designated starting node
- have a designated end node

Comment: Have you tried dijsktra alghoritem?

Comment: DFS is O(n), it's not clear that you can do better than that...

Comment: I dont think you can find anything much better than dfs, but look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857842/find-shortest-path/26858645#26858645

Comment: In case you don't get your answer here, ask the question again at http://math.stackexchange.com/ - they can suggest you an algorithm and then you can try to implement it yourself and ask Stack Overflow for help.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Discovery of nodes is `O(n)`, trying to find all different paths using DFS is not that simple, you are going to revisit "closed" nodes, since you need to create ALL paths.

Comment: @Jure Dijkstra's algorithm has nothing to do with that problem, Dijkstra is finding shortest path from a single source, it does NOT find all paths, this is not the shortest path problem here.

Comment: @amit: If the goal is to find all the paths, then I totally agree.  The title of this question implies a single path, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not really - you cannot make it significantly more efficient, because the output size itself is huge. The number of paths is exponential in the number of nodes, have a look at this simple example:

```
V = {a, b, c}, E = {(a,b), (a,c), (b,c)}
```

This looks pretty simple, there are "only" 2 none trivial paths in the graph leading to c. a->c, a->b->c.

Now, consider adding a node `d` with edges (d,a), (d,b) - you will have 3 paths leading to `c` from the new root, `d->a->b->c`, `d->a->c`, `d->b->c`, still not too bad, but notice what happens when adding `e` with `(e,d),(e,a)`, you will get one "family" of paths starting with `e->d` (3 above paths), and in addition, "family" of paths starting with "e->a" (2 paths). totaling in 5 paths. By repeating the process, you will get another two families, one with 5 paths, and the other with 3 paths. You probably start to understand that if you repeat the process `k` times, you will get `#fibo(k)` different paths, [but the fibonacci number is very, very big for inputs such as 100](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci%28100%29) (~354*10^20, and keeps growing fast).

Thus, whatever you do - finding all paths in a graph is going to be inefficient, except for some "easy" graphs, such as trees.

---

**tl;dr:** 

There are exponential number of paths leading to your target node, and finding all of them takes exponential time. DFS is a solid solution for this problem.