# "Least nodes traversed" shortest-path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the shortest-path from 2 points in a graph. However I don't mean shortest-path as in distance, I mean shortest-path as in least nodes traversed. So lets say the distance from A->B is 100, but A->C is 1, C->D is 1 and D->B is 1, I'd want A->B rather than A->C->D->B. Any thoughts?

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? Your distances are now 1. You can use this property to simplify the algorithm, of course. Regular queue instead of a min-queue, so you get BFS.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: Consider weight of every edge `1` then use one of shortest path algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857842/find-shortest-path/26858645#26858645